# How to check if player has already been selected using CodeIgniter Callback

Tags: validation, codeigniter

I wonder if anyone can help me out. I am trying to ensure that when a manager selects his players in his team to confirm a football result, he can only choose a player once.

So my validation callback starts here:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('P1', 'The Home Team cannot play with less than 7 players', 'trim|required|callback_player1_check');
```

I then have this callback_function:

```
function callback_player1_check()
{
    if ($this->fixtures_model->callback_player1_check()== TRUE)
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('P1', 'Player already selected');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

This callback function then links to this model function:

```
function callback_player1_check() {
$player_id1 = $this->input->post('P1');
$player_id2 = $this->input->post('P2');


if ($player_id1 == $player_id2)
                {
    return TRUE;
}       
}
```

So all I'm trying to do at the moment, is check if Player 1 (P1) and Player 2 (P2) are the same player. Which isn't working. If I can sort this out, I then need to check all players against each other to ensure a player is only selected once?

Any help would be great! Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to prefix the callback function with the word `callback_`

```
function player1_check() {
    $player_id1 = $this->input->post('P1');
    // etc
```

should do fine.

*edit*
See about [callbacks](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks) with regards to their naming convention.

Comment: I should clarify - it won't work if the prefix has been added, as CI looks for it automatically. I've updated my post however as it wasn't clear.

Comment: it's all fixed now. thanks for the guidance Ross :) i've used the same thing elsewhere in my project, just been a long week! thanks for the help.